# Are they needed for Python 3? SQLAlchemy Unicode and UnicodeText

Tags: python, unicode, sqlalchemy

I came across this code when I was trying Pyramid (Python) Tutorial - http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-blogr/en/latest/

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    Unicode,     #<- will provide Unicode field
    UnicodeText, #<- will provide Unicode text field
    DateTime,    #<- time abstraction field
)
```

It is just counter-intuitive to see "Unicode" and "UnicodeText" here instead simply "Text". I wonder if this is only to be compatible with Python 2.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html

Comment: yes. It doesn't say not to use Unicdoe or UnicodeText for python3.

Comment: The usage is not just for Python 2.  Its more about DBAPI support and the type of column intended to store the data.  From the docs: "For columns that are explicitly intended to store non-ASCII data, the Unicode or UnicodeText types should be used...indicate an underlying column type that directly supports unicode, such as NVARCHAR."

Comment: Also Unicode is for length-constrained fields similar to String and UnicodeText is for large text fields similar to Text.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it with Python 3.6.1 with sqlite. I input Chinese and French. Both work fine with just Text.

In conclusion, I don't need to fiddle with Unicode or UnicodeText.